# i have updated my wordpress to 6.3 and getting these errors. please help

Tags: plugins

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_queue_comments_for_comment_meta_lazyload() (previously declared in /home/admireho/public_html/wp-includes/comment.php:520) in /home/admireho/public_html/wp-includes/deprecated.php on line 4647

Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/admireho/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/admireho/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

The first error: it looks like your update failed: you've still got wp-includes/comment.php from a previous version of WordPress.

You should back up your site then follow the manual upgrade instructions here
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update
to replace your core files with a fresh copy. (I wouldn't bother disabling all the plugins etc. though)

---

I'm not sure what to make of the other two errors though. Hopefully they're related and the manual update will fix them too, but otherwise I'd guess you do have a problem with a plugin or theme.

Comment: thanks for the details, now i am getting  another error,                                                     Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_Block_Parser_Block, because the name is already in use in /home/admireho/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php on line 15